# Creating directory with foreign characters in php

Tags: php, character, mkdir

I am struggling with creating directories when foreign characters are in use.
There is no problem when I use this character 'ó', but when I try with
characters like ź,ż,ń,ć,ś there is no success.

Here is an example:

```
$directory = 'customers/ć';
$directory = mb_convert_encoding($directory, 'ISO-8859-1', 'utf-8'); 
//I use this line to correctly display the foreign character

if (!is_dir($directory)) {
    $mode = 0777;
    mkdir($directory, $mode, true);
}
else {
    echo "something went wrong";
}
```

Thank you
Robert

Comment: When you *echo $directory;* , does it generate the text with correct encoding?

Comment: This is what generates: Warning: mkdir(): Invalid path in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\test.php on line 8

Answer (score 0):

Convert to UTF-8 without specifying the current code:

```
$directory = mb_convert_encoding($directory, 'utf-8');
```